# WhatsApp backup

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup, whatsapp.app

I backed up my iPhone 11 iOS 14.7 through iCloud manually and then reset my iPhone because of the "Others" storage taking up to almost 50% of my storage. When the reset finished, all my apps started downloading and then they stuck. I did some research and found out that a soft restart would fix and it did. After the reset, all my apps started downloading, *except WhatsApp*, which kept stuck after downloading itself to a certain point.

I tried looking for almost every answer related do Whatsapp on the web, but could not find anything that I could use, then I uinstalled it and reinstalled it. The download went fine, but I could not restore my iCloud backup, neither could I see my WhatsApp 15gb backup on iCloud anymore.

Is there anything I can do? I have really important information there (most of us do, I guess.) I am pretty sure I did backup, or it wouldn't even have tried to download itself after all.

Any ideas on how to restore the missing WhatsApp data?

Comment: Why use WhatsApp as a backup? I would and do, store all my important files externally.